# Как дождаться завершения потока в асинхронном коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, asyncio, асинхронность

У меня есть телеграмм бот, написанный на aiogram взаимодействующий с ***БД*** - ***aiomysql***. И функция, которая принимает нажатие кнопки, имеет подпоток, в котором for loop обходит массив, создает конечное сообщение и отправляет его обратно в функцию **callback_query_keyboard**:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import keyboards as kb
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
import asyncio
import queue
import parser
import db

...

def create_message(response, out_queue):
    message = ''

    for i in response:
        message += f'• <a href="{i.get("link")}">{i.get("article")}</a>\n\n'

    out_queue.put(message)



@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    out_queue = queue.Queue()

    await connection.create_pool()
    response = await connection.get_data(callback_query.data)

    Thread(target=create_message, args=[response, out_queue]).start() #funciton create_message is run

    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=f'{out_queue.get(block=False)}', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)

...

def start_parsing():
    asyncio.run(parser.main())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=start_parsing).start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после запуска потока функция продолжает работать, а когда интерпретатор доходит до строки, где пользователь получает сообщение, ничего не происходит, и до завершения потока бот перестает отвечать. Я исправил эту ошибку, добавив **await asyncio.sleep()**:

```
 Thread(target=create_message, args=[response, out_queue]).start()

    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)  <--

    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=f'{out_queue.get(block=False)}', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Но я думаю, что это не лучшее решение проблемы, ведь:

1. Функция не работает, если поток работает более 0,2 секунды.
2. Функция простаивает, если подпоток выполнился раньше времени, указанного в **await asyncio.sleep(0.2)**

**Вопрос:** Как заменить **await asyncio.sleep(0.2)** на что-то лучшее или как переписать эту часть кода?

Comment: Вы забыли добавить в вопрос, что у вас запущенно с помощью multiprocessing два процесса(не считая основного процесса) у которых одна общая база данных и добавьте импорты. Надаело гадать какую вы используете базу данных.

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=start_parsing).start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True) БД-aiomysql

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, а не в комментарий, добавте импорты. Thread (модуль threading?), db? start_parsing + db?  В данном коде Thread не имеет смысла. Что с Thread что и без Thread код будет выполнятся по времени одинаково. Почему db.DbConnection()  инициализировали базу данных в функций, а не в начале кода?. Почему  использовали многопроцессорность вместо асинхронного кода? Пробывалм запустить код без start_parsing?

Comment: Вопрос исправил. Без Thread цикл for, который генерирует финальное сообщение в функции create_message()  блокирует бота и тот не отвечает. Если это все таки можно реализовать асинхронно, то подскажите как. В одном процессе работает сам бот, в другом работает парсер, который каждую минуту обновляет базу данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# 1
def create_message(response):
    message = ''
    for i in response:
        message += f'• <a href="{i.get("link")}">{i.get("article")}</a>\n\n'
    return message

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await connection.create_pool()
    response = await connection.get_data(callback_query.data)

    message = await asyncio.to_thread(create_message, response)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=message, parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)

# 2 в чем проблема этого кода?
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await connection.create_pool()
    response = await connection.get_data(callback_query.data)

    message = ''
    for i in response:
        message += f'• <a href="{i.get("link")}">{i.get("article")}</a>\n\n'
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text=message)
```

Comment: Проблема второго решения заключается в том, что цикл в котором создается сообщение блокирует бота и тот не отвечает пока цикл не закончит свое выполнение.  То есть если представить, что в переменной **response**  будет действительно много данных, которые будут обрабатываться условно 0.5 сек. , то и бот на полсекунды зависнет и отвечать никому не будет.  И чтобы не потерять асинхронность всего кода создается отдельная функция, которая запускается  в новом потоке. Без нового потока строки **Process(target=start_parsing).start() ** и **executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)**  не работают.

Comment: А почему общий ответ?